# Struts <s:if tag does not evaluate while using information from getters

Tags: jsp, struts2, ognl

Trying to evaluate the following but not seem to work

```
  <s:set name="infoType" value='%{"info.aero.aeroType"}' />
  <s:if test='%{#infoType == "A"}'>
    <span> got it </span>
</s:if>
```

the return type for `aeroType` is String that is set in a Java class and it returns a alphabet "A" or "B". If infoType is A, I need to perform some calculation. How to get this working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use **var** instead of **name**, [because it is deprecated](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/set.html)
2. [General info on validating one character Strings](http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/why-wont-the-if-tag-evaluate-a-one-char-string.html) (you are already flipping quotes, then this part is right)
3. This is your real problem: you are putting double quotes around your `<s:set` **value**; this way you are telling OGNL to take that literal String, instead of reading an object from the stack;

then change this

```
<s:set name="infoType" value='%{"info.aero.aeroType"}' />
```

to this

```
<s:set var="infoType" value="%{info.aero.aeroType}" />
```

and it wil work